# Dynamics SDK v9.1 - iOS Simulator on M1 Apple Silicon Support

Tags: ios, xcode, blackberry, ios-simulator, blackberry-dynamics

The [release notes](https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios/9_0/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios-relnotes/BlackBerry-Dynamics-SDK-for-iOS-version-9-0) for Dynamics SDK v9.0.x mentions that iOS Simulator isn't supported on M1 Macs.

> On Apple M1 devices, the SDK does not support building and debugging BlackBerry Dynamics apps on the iOS simulator. As a workaround you can build and debug on physical iOS devices.

Looking at the [release notes](https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios/9_1/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-ios-relnotes/BlackBerry-Dynamics-SDK-for-iOS-version-9-1) for Dynamics SDK v9.1.x, there is no mention of M1 Macs. Is this now supported? If so, is there any special configuration required beyond normally upgrading the SDK? I've upgraded the SDK to v9.1.x but I get `Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GDiOS` error when trying to build for an iOS simulator.

- MacOS 11.2.3
- Xcode 12.4

Edit:
Running Xcode under Rosetta seems to work fine. But still looking forward to native support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackBerry Dynamics SDK version 9.1 does not support M1 Apple Silicon.  Currently, BlackBerry Dynamics apps are blocked from activating on an M1 powered Mac.  BlackBerry is working on supporting this architecture, which will be available in a future BlackBerry Dynamics SDK release.